# COM method offsets in Delphi

Tags: delphi, com, vtable

In Delphi, how do I find out the the address of a COM method?
I can hardcode the offsets

```
//0 is the offset of the QueryInterface method
p := TPonterArray(pointer(SomeInterface)^)[0];
```

but I would prefer to use symbolic names. The folllowing obviously does not work:

```
var M : TMethod;
...
M := TMethod(SomeInterface.QueryInterface);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Delphi takes away a lot of all the gory COM details, I think you want to do way too much yourself. What are you trying to achieve? Making your own COM server or using an existing one?

Comment: Do you want the numeric offset of the method in the interface (e.g., IUnknown.QueryInterface is 0), the address of the method in the class that implements that interface method (e.g., @TInterfacedObject.QueryInterface), or the address of the stub code generated to link an interface call to the corresponding object method? The latter is stored in the class's interface table.

Comment: @The_Fox: Neither: I am intercepting calls to an external COM object using Win32Hook.pas. 

@Rob Kennedy: There is no TInterfacedObject class - I only have an interface implemented by an external dll.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `vmtoffset` assembler directive to get the byte offset of an interface method relative to the start of the interface's method table. Take a look at the implementation of `_IntfCast` in *System.pas*, for example:

```
call dword ptr [eax] + vmtoffset IInterface.QueryInterface
...
call dword ptr [eax] + vmtoffset IInterface._Release
```

The first expression adds 0; the second, 8.

You cannot parameterize those expressions, though. They're compile-time constants, so you cannot choose which method you want at run time. You need to have all possible method names represented in advance.

All you *really* need to hook is `QueryInterface`. Once you have that, you can return whatever proxy object you want that can intercept calls to all the other methods.

Comment: This looks promising... I'll try it later today and post the results.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think Delphi supports that.  Hardcoding the offsets is probably the only thing that will work, since the compiler doesn't count interface methods as symbols whose value can be assigned to a function pointer, the way object methods or standalone functions can.

Why are you trying to do this, BTW?

Comment: I am intercepting calls to an external COM object using Win32Hook.pas - just a logging feature for my OutlookSpy (http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/)

Comment: BTW, Delphi compiler obviously knows the method offsets, I am just trying to find a way to do the same instead of using hardcoded offsets.

Comment: Yeah, the compiler knows about it, but as far as I can tell, there's no way to get at it directly.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is wrong because an interface reference is not a pointer to an interface method table but **a pointer to pointer to an interface method table**. That is how Delphi interfaces are implemented on binary level. It is hard to say more and point out to the error in your code because you have not given a code example that can be compiled. Use the following code to convert interface reference to method pointer correctly, the idea was taken from [Barry Kelly's demonstration of creating a method pointer from a method reference](http://blog.barrkel.com/2010/01/using-anonymous-methods-in-method.html):

```
procedure IntRefToMethPtr(const IntRef; var MethPtr; MethNo: Integer);
type
  TVtable = array[0..999] of Pointer;
  PVtable = ^TVtable;
  PPVtable = ^PVtable;
begin
  // QI=0, AddRef=1, Release=2, etc
  TMethod(MethPtr).Code := PPVtable(IntRef)^^[MethNo];
  TMethod(MethPtr).Data := Pointer(IntRef);
end;
```

If you prefer symbolic names for MethNo you are better to declare them yourself as offset constants

Comment: No, an interface variable in Delphi is a pointer to a v-table.

Comment: No, Dmitry, Serg is right. An interface variable cannot just be a pointer to a vtable. All instances of the class share a single vtable, just like non-interface classes. Consider C++, in which there is no difference between interfaces and ordinary classes. An object pointer is not just a vtable pointer, so neither is an interface pointer.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: thank you, the question forced me to write a blog post about Delphi interfaces:
http://sergworks.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/delphi-interfaces-on-binary-level/

Answer (score 1):

> Two additional directives allow assembly code to access dynamic and
>   virtual methods: VMTOFFSET and DMTINDEX.
>
> VMTOFFSET retrieves the offset in bytes of the virtual method pointer
>   table entry of the virtual method argument from the beginning of the
>   virtual method table (VMT). This directive needs a fully specified
>   class name with a method name as a parameter (for example,
>   TExample.VirtualMethod), or an interface name and an interface method
>   name.
>
> DMTINDEX retrieves the dynamic method table index of the passed
>   dynamic method. This directive also needs a fully specified class name
>   with a method name as a parameter, for example,
>   TExample.DynamicMethod. To invoke the dynamic method, call
>   System.@CallDynaInst with the (E)SI register containing the value
>   obtained from DMTINDEX.

[docwiki.embarcadero.com](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Assembler_Syntax)

Here the code to get the needed method pointer

```
function GetMethodPointer(const IntRef: IInterface): Pointer; assembler;
asm
  mov eax, [IntRef] 
  add eax, vmtoffset ISomeInterface.MemberMethod
  mov eax, [eax]
end;
```